# How to fix that taxes are not showing in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am using PrestaShop 1.6.0.9.

I have added a tax rule for our local Spanish Sales tax rate at 21%. All of my products have this listed as the tax rule to follow. In our area I am required to charge this flat tax rate to all purchases regardless of the shipping destination. When I enter the prices for the products the tax rule is not showing directly. I have to click 2-3 times on save and stay button then it shows in the back office and then it comes and I have to select it every time and the separate line of tax is showing in the shopping cart but tax is always showing 0.

I have changed all the things but unable to show the tax in the shopping cart. I am also required to show the amount of tax on a separate line in the checkout process.

Currently I have the settings as follows.

**Product set up:**

Tax Rule is set to my special tax rule added as an additional option in the state taxes.

**Tax Options:**

Enable Tax: Yes
Display Taxes in Cart: Yes
Base on: Invoice Address
Use EcoTax: No

The taxes are not being calculated nor are they being displayed in the shopping cart or during the checkout process. Is there something I need to be doing differently?

This is the last thing to do before I go live and if I can't get it fixed.

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but maybe it can help someone else. In the Prestashop 1.6 admin area, you need to click on **Localization > Taxes** from the left menu. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen and you need to select "**Enable tax**" then **save**.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar case. 
I imported the localization pack ....and it worked.
Didn't do anything else, just import localization pack.